# check if directory exists in excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a user enter in some information `MyBarcode and MyScan` that will be used to create a directory.  If that directory exists I want to display a message indicating that and go back to the step where the user can enter in data.  The `vba` is below and seems to function except for the directory check which I need some help on. I hope that it is a good start. Thank you :).

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim MyBarCode   As String      ' Enter Barcode
Dim MyScan      As String      ' Enter ScanDate
Dim MyDirectory As String

MyBarCode = Application.InputBox("Please enter the last 5 digits of the barcode", "Bar Code", Type:=2)

If MyBarCode = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
Do
    MyScan = Application.InputBox("Please enter scan date", "Scan Date", Date - 1, Type:=2)
    If MyScan = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
    If IsDate(MyScan) Then Exit Do
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date format. ", vbExclamation, "Invalid Date Entry"
Loop

'Create nexus directory and folder check
MyDirectory = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy") & "\"
If MyDirectory("MyDirectory") Then
    MsgBox "Folder exists! Please try again", Goto MyBarcode

Else
If Dir(MyDirectory, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir MyDirectory
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `Dir` and `GetAttr` functions to check if directory exists like so:

```
Function DirectoryExists(Directory As String) As Boolean
    DirectoryExists = False
    If Not Dir(Directory, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        If GetAttr(Directory) = vbDirectory Then
            DirectoryExists = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Sub TestDirectoryExists()
    Dim Directory As String
    Directory = "c:\src"                    ' is a valid directory
    Debug.Print DirectoryExists(Directory)  ' shows True
    Directory = "c:\src1"                   ' is not a valid directory
    Debug.Print DirectoryExists(Directory)  ' shows False
    Directory = "x:\src"                    ' is not a valid drive
    Debug.Print DirectoryExists(Directory)  ' shows False
    Directory = "c:\test.txt"               ' is a file
    Debug.Print DirectoryExists(Directory)  ' shows False
End Sub
```

When we use [Dir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) with vbDirectory attribute, we are looking for folders in addition to files with no special attributes. To confirm that we are indeed looking for a folder, we'd use 
[GetAttr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hds568h4(v=vs.90).aspx) and check that the path is indeed a folder.

Feel free to use this function in your button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
If GetAttr(Directory) AND vbDirectory Then
```

instead of

```
If GetAttr(Directory) = vbDirectory Then
```

according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-DE/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getattr-function#remarks)?